# How to run multiple insert statements in a transaction in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, psql

```
BEGIN;

    DECLARE o_id int;
    DECLARE p_id int;

    INSERT INTO properties (address, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES ('100 street, city, country, 1b1 b1b', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
    
    INSERT INTO ownerships (share, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
    RETURNING id INTO o_id;
    
    INSERT INTO profiles (first_name, last_name, created_at, updated_at)
    values ('j', 'p', current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
    RETURNING id INTO p_id;
    
    INSERT INTO profile_ownerships (profile_id, ownership_id, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (o_id, p_id, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
    
COMMIT;
```

I'm trying to run these insert rows into properties, profiles, and ownerships. Then return the profile and ownership id's for the joining table, profile_ownerships. The above sql is returning an error around 'returning id into ownership_id;' and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why don’t you share the complete error message? This code will not work anyway, declare is used for cursors.

Comment: I would share an error message if I had one. All it says is ERROR:  syntax error at or near "returning id into ownership_id"

Comment: Ok, that's clear, but how did you get this part working: declare ownership_id int; That's not valid SQL.

Comment: Postgresql has a declare keyword for creating variables. https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/declare_vars.php I've seen in different examples that the declare should be outside of the transaction. Is that the way it should be written?

Comment: That website forgot to mention that this is for the plpqsl language only. Not for SQL. There are more issues on this site, I wouldn’t recommend this as a reliable source. Use the manual for the version you use

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be what I was looking for. Still not sure why it needed to be wrapped in a DO .. END block, though. So if someone has an answer to that, I'd appreciate it.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    o_id INTEGER;
    p_id INTEGER;

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO properties (address, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES ('test 7', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

    INSERT INTO ownerships (shares, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (4, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
    RETURNING id INTO o_id;

    INSERT INTO profiles (first_name, last_name, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES ('p', 'j', current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
    RETURNING id INTO p_id;

    INSERT INTO profile_ownerships (profile_id, ownership_id, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (p_id, o_id, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
    
END $$;
```

Comment: Plpgsql is a [block structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)d language. Unlike T-sql you cannot just declare variables except within a block. There are 2 basic methods to introduce a block: Create function/procedure or DO. (Another is a nesting within another block, but the outer most must be initiated as indicated.)